# Laravel middleware doesnt work to filter logged users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-authentication

Im trying to use middleware to filter users who hasnt logged in.  Somehow users who has logged out still can get inside the routes that are protected by the middleware. I dont know which is the problem here. Here are the files

my route

```
Route::view("/",'loginmhs');
Route::get('/loginmhs', function () {
    return view('loginmhs');
});
Route::post("mhslogin",[LoginController::class,'mhslogin']);
Route::get('/logout',[LoginController::class,'logout']);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['protectedPage']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboardmhs');
    });
    Route::get('/profil', function () {
        return view('profil');
    });
});
```

LoginController

```
public function mhslogin(Request $req){
  $datareq = $req->input();

  $data = DB::table('tbl_mahasiswa')
  ->join('tbl_prodi', 'tbl_mahasiswa.id_prodi', '=', 'tbl_prodi.id_prodi')
  ->where('nim', $req->nim)->first();
  if(!$data){
    return redirect('/loginmhs')->with('alert','NIM tidak ditemukan...Cek kembali NIM anda.')->with('cek','dikirim');
  }
  if($req->password == $data->password){
    $req->session()->put('nim', $data->nim);
    $req->session()->put('nama', $data->nama);
    $req->session()->put('email', $data->email);
    $req->session()->put('password', $data->password);
    $req->session()->put('stambuk', $data->stambuk);
    $req->session()->put('id_prodi', $data->id_prodi);
    $req->session()->put('nama_prodi', $data->nama_prodi);
    return redirect('/profil');
  }
  return redirect('/loginmhs')->with('alert','Password anda salah!');
}
public function logout(){
  if(session()->has('nim')||session()->has('nip')){
    session()->forget('nim');
    session()->forget('nama');
    session()->forget('email');
    session()->forget('password');
    session()->forget('stambuk');
    session()->forget('id_prodi');
    session()->forget('nama_prodi');
    session()->save();
  }
  return redirect('/');
}
```

Middleware loginSessionCheck

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!session()->has('nim')){
      return redirect('/')
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

kernel

```
'protectedPage' => [
      \App\Http\Middleware\loginSessionCheck::class,
    ],
```

Comment: firstly, why don't you use laravel built-in `auth` middlware? `Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']], function(){`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that for the routes you are trying to protect doesn't have access to `session`. You must also include `web` middleware group to the group containing protected routes.

```php
Route::middleware(['web', 'protectedPage'])
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
            return view('dashboardmhs');
        });
        Route::get('/profil', function () {
            return view('profil');
        });
    });
```